# The workspace in Tkitner Canvas is smaller than the widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to output some rectangles with text in a grid. But the second column is not drawn all the way through.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH

class Flowchart(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack()

    def rec_with_text(self, x1: int, y1: int, text: str):
        # x1 = x1-50
        my_test = self.canvas.create_text(x1+1, y1, text=text, width=100, anchor="nw")
        coords_text = self.canvas.bbox(my_test)
        print(coords_text)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x1+100, coords_text[3], width=2)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x600+100+100")
    ex = Flowchart()
    ex.master.title("Рисуем линии 2")
    ex.rec_with_text(100, 100, "There will also be a tex0")
    ex.rec_with_text(300, 100, "There will also be a tex1")
    ex.rec_with_text(300, 200, "There will also be a tex2")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

I am trying to create my own class that will help me to work comfortably with `tkinter.Canvas` methods. I want the parameters I pass to `root.geometry("600x600+100+100")` to correspond to the workspace, not the width and height of the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem is the opposite: the canvas is smaller than the workspace. The problem is that you aren't instructing `pack` to fill  the frame with the canvas, so the canvas stays at its original size. You can easily visualize this by temporarily giving the canvas a distinctive background color.

The simple solution is to do this:

```
self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, that helped. Thank you!